# Is it a problem to have water around a bath drain flange?

Tags: drain, bathtub, caulk

Installed a new bath and drain and it drains fine but the fit is not 100% flat and leaves a ring of water around. This was still lying around a day later so may not be an issue, I just don't like the idea of water sitting there on the metal permanently. This is a humid climate and might sit there for days.

Any suggestions apart from caulking to create a slope ?

[image]

The drain is a EZYFLOW 40mm Popup waste EZY-A245-MB. Bath is a Decina Cortex 1675

https://linsol.com.au/products/ezyflow-40mm-pop-up-plug-waste-matte-black/

https://decina.com.au/product/cortez-1520-1670-inset-bath-white/?v=6cc98ba2045f

Comment: Could you share an image or two to better show this?

Comment: Usually a little sitting water around the drain is not an issue, it tends to stay there because of water's surface tension properties more than anything else

Comment: Do you know what kind of metal your drain is?

Comment: I would suggest reinstalling the popup drain piece, eliminating the gasket under the top flange and using some non-staining, plastic-safe plumber's putty instead.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure you assembled the drain according to the diagram. I made the mistake years ago of putting a washer/gasket that was intended to go *under* the tub on top, out of my faulty assumption. It resulted in what you see here.

Then, consider that plastic parts are necessarily thicker than metal ones. Virtually all drain flanges result in a little water retention, and this one has a little more.

Finally, no drain allows 100% drainage (mostly due to surface tension in water). You'll still have to clean that area of soap scum and mildew. It shouldn't cause undue corrosion. This doesn't really change anything in that regard.